# How to make Wi-Fi more reliable in model 3B+

Tags: wifi, wireless

I have a model 3B+ a bit too far from the wireless router, but other devices work just fine in the same room.
Is there any configuration setting that can help get a more reliable connection?
I don't care for speed at all but need connections to stay up.
Here's what `iwconfig` says (as you see I already tried turning off power saving).

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BUNNY9"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 38:43:7D:A7:14:37   
          Bit Rate=57.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I'm aware there are similar questions but didn't find a satisfactory recent answer / exactly the same use case.

The rpi is in a plastic case.

Comment: do you have it in a case at all?

Comment: Good point.  A case can make it worse if it is metal.  There's a lot of radio related things you can do to improve the signal, and you can also use an external usb wifi that could be aimed or positioned more easily than the pi.

Comment: Answered, it's in a plastic case. Is there a tutorial or guide on the "radio related things" one can do? Happy to RTFM but don't know where to start...

Comment: Radio related things... move it a fraction of a quarter wavelength to find the best fresnel zone for multipath (watch signal strength to find the sweet spot).  Try putting metal (like a flat piece of foil) behind the antenna on the side opposite the wifi access point (a few cm away or less from the antenna) to reflect and double the signal.  Use an external usb wifi on an extension cable to make positioning  easier.  Some of these can make it worse if done wrong, so watch signal strength to find out if you are dong it right.

Comment: Thank you @user10489 these tips are helpful, I've improved signal a bit. I haven't solved my problem but I have a follow up question if you don't mind. Another computer, in the same room, has "Link Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm Tx-Power=14 dBm" and works flawlessly. The rpi has "Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm Tx-Power=31 dBm" so I don't get why it doesn't work better, rather than worse.

Comment: Most likely explanation is that the built in pi wifi interface is lower quality / lower sensitivity / has more near by noise.  External wifi usb dongle may or may not improve that situation as well.